# How to diagnose indicator problem on VW Polo 2001

Tags: electrical, vw, polo, indicators

I have a VW polo, hazard lights and RHS indicator seem to be working as expected. However the LHS indicator stops working intermittently, ie turn it on, works for a bit then just stops clicking and light goes off - the stalk is still in the LHS indicator position.

The hazard lights work and the LHS works sometimes so this leads me to believe it is an issue with the wiring or connectors?

Looking for suggestions on diagnosing and fixing the fault.

Comment: Check the wiring and connectors - especially connectors - one could have worked loose... Just follow the wires...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!